# Session variable changes after two reloads of the page why?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

**Main.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
msgbox("Are you sure?", "confirm");
$Result = $_SESSION['id'] ;
print "<p id='txt'> </p>";
if($Result == 1 )
    echo "Result is true";
elseif ( $Result == 2 ) 
    print "<br><br>Return value is '$Result'";
function msgbox($msg, $type)
{
    if ($type == "confirm")
    {
        print "<script src='Validate.js'></script>";
        print "<script> ret = confirm ('$msg') ;
        if (ret)
            Write_to_variable('1');
        else
            Write_to_variable('2');
        </script>";
?>
```

**Validate.js**

```
function Write_to_variable( value ) 
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else 
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","Variable.php?id="+value,true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

**Variable.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( $_GET['id'] ) 
{
    $_SESSION['variable'] = $_GET['id'];
    print $_SESSION['variable'];
}
?>
```

What I am trying to do is,

Getting the value from the javascript confirm box and store return value of confirm box to php `SESSION` variable using Ajax. In Ajax File I just assigning `$_SESSION['id']= $_GET['id']`. When the program get execute, I pressed `OK` from the confirm box. It assign `1` to the session variable of `id`. If I pressed `cancel` next time the value doesn't changed, when I am tried to pressed `cancel` another time, the value of session have changed to `id` as 2. What is the problem, any suggestions and solution are kindly accepted.

I cant find what is logic hidden behind it. I can clearly see what is returns and what ajax returns but the session variable used in the main.php is changing after second click.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The quotes are messed up on the `print "<scipt src=Validate.js` line.

Comment: is `$_SESSION['id']= $_GET['id']` and not `S_SESSION['id']= $_GET['id']`

Comment: Changes made please... Any help?

Comment: is your ajax call working fine??

Answer (score 0):

seems there's nothing wrong just try

1. console log your java script parameters and check for errors
2. use alert and check what what value is passed to the ajax file

3.use `die()` in your ajax file and check for mismatch.

Comment: No problem in ajax and return value of ajax. But the session variable which is used in the main.php is changing after second click.

Comment: try using two sessions with different names and check whether the same happens

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem working on Drupal.

Session variable just not save after ajax call: when I reload page, session was the same as before my ajax call and save only second page reload.

I fix it using Drupal function `drupal_session_commit();`

Function code you can find below https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/drupal_session_commit/7.x